# making a utility to run C# code through command

Tags: c#, command, command-prompt

I am trying to learn how to create a utility to run my C# code that I have written through visual studio. I would like to be able to run it through command prompt. I have looked online for a how-to guide on getting started but I seem to not be able to find any. If you could help me understand how it works/give me and example, I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks you!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I need some clarification, do you want to create a C# application that writes to the command prompt (i.e. ping, tracert, xcopy, etc) OR are you looking to create a tool that you can run from the command prompt that compiles your C# code?

Comment: I want to create a tool that I can run through command prompt @Sane

Comment: Then the first comment by emd, is the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit - if the question is: "How to create console application in Visual Studio?" - @emd provided good link: [How to: Create a C# Console Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer to: "How to create utility that takes CS file and run it as an executable?"

If you projects are all in single file (or group of CS files) without any non-trivial configuration than basic call to `CSC.exe` will produce ".EXE" to run. You can easily wrap call to `csc.exe` and execution of resulting ".exe" into ".CMD" file and (if you want to) associate that CMD with CS extension so entering CS file name will compile and execute code.

If project is more complicated - use MSBUID to build *.csproj file and than execute resulting EXE

For bonus points you can merge ".CS" and ".CMD" in one single file by wrapping `CSC.exe` call in `/**/` comments that are ignored by Windows CMD shell.

Note: `CSC.exe` is installed as part of .Net Framework, so you don't even need VS on the machine to use it. Location - `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe`